# Import discounted price (list price) from csv Shopware 6

Tags: shopware, shopware6

Is it possible to enter discounted price data via CSV (not manually filling in the fields)? Previously I've used object types in the CSV import such as

> price.default.listPrice

Product data was successfully entered but discounted data was still not entered into product data. I've read the documentation and haven't found a solution yet. [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxFug.png)

Comment: This question is entirely lacking in detail. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works and what our expectations are before you begin posting, as was suggested to you when you created your account.

Comment: I will edit my question

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. You can check out this document that provide supported fields https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-en/settings/importexport#object-type-product

column name `price.DEFAULT.listPrice`

Comment: I have tried this before but it can't be solved, list price gross still empty after successfully import.

Comment: did you replace DEFAULT with currency? 

`Standard gross price. DEFAULT can be replaced by the respective currency. e.g. EUR`

Comment: yes it was, when I export it with price.DEFAULT.listPrice it will showing error messages like ```Error
0: Object of class Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Pricing\Price could not be converted to string```